# A binning procedure in R?

Tags: r, binning

I am struggling with putting into an R code/script the following binning "algorithm/procedure", which may be similar to those used for binned Kernel Density estimation :

Say we have some data:

```
set.seed(12345) # setting seed
x<-rnorm(100)   # generating data
```

and a grid for estimation (e.g. Kernel Density Estimation):

`y<-seq(from=min(x)-1, to=max(x)+1, by=0.01) # grid for binning`

1. The objective is to bin `y` into some number of equal intervals/bins so that each bin contains at least one observation from `x` (number of bins = empty bins are not allowed). For this particular example I am aware that such number of bins is equal to `17` but I would like `R` to automatically determine such "optimal/maximum" number of bins and bin `y` accordingly.
2. Say the desired number of equal intervals/bins is determined then one can use (at least from my active googling) the following to bin `y`:

`nbins<-cut(y, 17) # binning`

which does the job very well as it splits `y` exactly the way I want but how to determine the center of each bin (perhaps using `median()`?) as well as the number of `x` which fall into each bin?

There is an interesting package `binr` with very good functional, however, it does not seem to offer exactly what I am looking for. I would be really grateful for any hints, tips, suggestions ...

```
EDIT: an example of a code with which I ended up with for my calculations.
```

First, I would like to say special thanks @missuse for the help, effort and input. Second, I would like to apologize for my ignorance (hopefully due to the lack of experience with R, and programming in general) of some `base` R functions.

I was transforming and experimenting with the code @missuse developed for my calculations, however, the problem of missing `x` constantly was coming up, and often required manual adjustments for different data sets. Especially, when I was experimenting with break points determined by sample quantiles of my data. Also `cut` function appeared to be quite sensitive in my view (note: this is probably quite subjective due to my goals, data etc.). So, the other day tired of constant adjustments and going through `help()` command for various R functions, `hist()` came to my rescue and resolved almost all my binning problems. So below is very straightforward illustration to determine how many `x` fall into each bin and how to determine bin center of each bin:

```
hist(x, breaks=c(-5:5), plot=FALSE)$counts # for bin counts 
hist(x, breaks=c(-5,5), plot=FALSE)$mids   # for bin centers
```

Above I hypothetically select desired breaks, you can build up a function based on the `cut` function the way you desire and cut your grid for estimation accordingly. @missuse below provides a good foundation for setting breaks with `cut`, just make sure your data spans across your `breaks` specification in `hist()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps something like this:

data:

```
 set.seed(12345) # setting seed
 x<-rnorm(100)
 y<-seq(from=min(x)-1, to=max(x)+1, by=0.01) 
 nbins<-cut(y, 17)
```

step 1:

for all possible cuts find if any elements of x is in all bins:

```
p =lapply(3 : length(x), function(i){
  nbins<-cut(y, i)
  z = lapply(levels(nbins), function(j) y[nbins == j])
  sumi = lapply(z, function(i) {
    mini = min(i)
    maxi = max(i)
    sum(mini <= x & x <= maxi)
  }
  )
  return(sum(unlist(sumi)>0) == length(sumi))
}
)

which(unlist(p)), only first 4 satisfy the rule, so 3, 4, 5, 6
```

step 2:

put values in a list according to bin:

```
z = lapply(levels(nbins), function(x) y[nbins == x] )
```

perform function of interest per list item

```
lapply(z, median) #median for each bin

lapply(z, function(i) {
  mini = min(i)
  maxi = max(i)
  sum(mini <= x & x <= maxi)
}
) #number of elements of x in each bin
```

Based on the result some bins have 0 elements from x so bins 17 does not solve your problem at step 1.

EDIT: on the problem with missing `x`:

```
sum(unlist(lapply(z, function(i) {
  mini = min(i)
  maxi = max(i)
  sum(mini <= x & x <= maxi)
}
))) is less than 100 in many cases
```

which x are missing:

```
nbins<-cut(y, 8) 
    z = lapply(levels(nbins), function(x) y[nbins == x])
    gix = lapply(z, function(i) {
      mini = min(i)
      maxi = max(i)
      x[mini <= x & x <= maxi]
    }
    )
  x[!x %in% unlist(gix)]

 #-1.6620502 -0.8115405
```

so they should be in bins `(-1.67,-0.812]`  and `(-0.812,0.0446]` 
  and are in fact close to the bin cutoff.

This is happening since `y` is rounded at two decimals. For instance if we bin a sequence: 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, and 0.04 and cut it in 2 bins that split the data at 0.025, we would get bin 1: 0.01 - 0.02 and bin 2: 0.03 - 0.04, if we then try to assign some random `x` value from range 0.01 - 0.04, based only on `y` values present in bins we would not assign anything in 0.02 - 0.03 range - hence the missing values.

A possible solution is to round `x` to 2 since you already did a `seq` rounded to 2. Or do a seq with `y` values rounded at 4 - 6 decimals and round `x` accordingly. Or instead of assigning `x` based on `min(yi)` and `max(yi)` in bin i, replace `min(yi) <= x` with `max(yi-1) < x` (max(yi) from bin i-1), and replace  `x <= max(yi)` with `x < min(yi+1)`. 
Here is the simplest solution with rounding x at 2 decimals.

```
p =lapply(2 : length(x), function(i){
  nbins<-cut(y, i)
  z = lapply(levels(nbins), function(j) y[nbins == j])
  sumi = lapply(z, function(i) {
    mini = min(i)
    maxi = max(i)
    p = round(x, 2)
    sum(mini <= p & p <= maxi)
  }
  )
  return(sum(unlist(sumi)>0) == length(sumi))
}
)
```

that will at least solve the problem of missing x elements

the solution to the optimization problem is the same tho

`which(unlist(p))`, only first 4 satisfy the rule, so 3, 4, 5, 6

Comment: Many thanks as it works very well for finding a median (center for each bin) but unfortunately it provides lengths of `y` in each bin, while I am looking for how many of `x` belong (fall into) to each bin ...

Comment: @EmptyHead Maybe `table(nbins)`.

Comment: @EmptyHead updated, check if output corresponds to desired.

Comment: @missuse if you do `sum(unlist(lapply(z, function(i) {
  mini=min(i)
  maxi=max(i)
  sum(mini<=x & x<=maxi)
})))` total number of observations in bins is 97 ... so I immediately tried to run your code over `y<-seq(from=min(x)-1, to=max(x)+1, by=0.001)` and it gave the right number of observations in each bin, so you are very right, I might have used a different seed when was calculating number of observations in a bin initially ... huge thanks for your input, effort and time!

Comment: @EmptyHead I also observed the `sum = 97`, thought it was odd so I run some tests. see EDIT.

Comment: @missuse for the code I am building upon this binning procedure, I have to use quite an intense grid (`y` ~ should be a sequence of 10 000 observations or more). Such precision of `y` eliminates omitted (not included) `x` for some bins in my particular case, however, rounding `x` is also interesting if necessary, I may be posting some updates later which method may be preferred when and why from my practical experience